# Кеширование страниц в wpf

Tags: wpf

Всем доброго времени суток. Проблема такова, что при переключении с одной страницы, в которой вводится и выводится информация, на последующие и возвращение на на страницу где происходил вывод, информации как таковой нету.

Comment: Покажите код. Вы каждый раз создаете новый экземпляр страницы?

Comment: Нет, у меня уже имеется несколько страниц, и при переходе с одной на другие страницы информация которая выводилась в textblok пропадает